# ¿Cómo unir letras para crear la palabra original después de iterar dos veces y añadirlas a una lista?

Tags: python, lista, bucles, python-3.9

Tengo una lista de palabras y debo convertirlas en jeringoso para luego añadirlas a la lista 'palabras jeringoso'. Lo que hice hasta ahora fue iterar 2 veces. La primera iteración me da las palabras y la segunda las letras, luego modifico las vocales para convertir la palabra en jeringoso y acá viene mi problema: me queda una lista con todas las letras de las palabras convertidas en jeringoso pero la cuestión es ¿de que manera puedo pasar esas palabras a la lista?

```
lista_palabras = ['banana', 'mandarina']

palabras_jeringoso = []

vocales = 'AEIOUaeiou'

for palabra in lista_palabras:

    for letra in palabra:

        if letra in vocales:

            palabras_jeringoso += letra + 'p' + letra

        else:

            palabras_jeringoso += letra

print(palabras_jeringoso)

>>>['b', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'a']
```

Comment: ¿Qué es jerigonza?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es unir los elementos de una lista el método `.join()` te puede servir, pero antes hay que arreglar algunas cositas en tu código para evitar hacer *trabajo de más*. No tocaré nada de tu lógica, solo moveré algunas cosas.

Lo conveniente sería obtener solo una lista por cada palabra, por lo que pondremos la creación de la lista dentro del primer ciclo `for`, a su vez moveremos el `print` dentro del primer ciclo (pero al final) para imprimir la lista. También usaré *f-strings* para hacer la concatenación.

```py
lista_palabras = ['banana', 'mandarina']

vocales = 'aeiou'

for palabra in lista_palabras:
    palabras_jeringoso = []

    for letra in palabra:
        if letra.lower() in vocales:
            palabras_jeringoso += f"{letra}p{letra}"
        else:
            palabras_jeringoso += letra

    print("".join(palabras_jeringoso))
```

El método `.join()` *junta* los elementos de la lista de acuerdo al carácter que se le pase, en este caso un *caracter totalmente vacío* (`""`), lo que quiere decir, que por cada elemento de la lista añadirá ese caracter, puedes jugar poniendo distintas cosas como `",".join(palabras_jeringoso)`. Una pista para reducir tu código es usar un string en vez de una lista :D.

Comment: No sabía que se podía sumar un objeto a una lista y este se agregaba al final :o

Comment: todo se agrega al final, si se quiere agregar en una posición específica se utiliza `insert()`.

Comment: Eso lo sabía, pero hasta ahora usaba append y extend para agregar cosas al final.

Comment: ahora sabes otra forma :D